# Single select model stored and retrieved as an array

Tags: angularjs

I store my data in a array for product.taxonmyF1 and product.taxonomyF2. I need to switch between multi select and single select based certain criteria. If I have a single select it does not preselect the select box because it doesn't expect an array.  What is the best way to implement this?

Here is how my code looks:

```
    <!-- Coding/marking -->
    <div ng-if="product.taxonomy == CONSTANTS.CODING_MARKING" layout="row">
      <md-input-container class="md-default-theme full-width-select">
        <md-select ng-model="product.taxonomyF1" placeholder="Select All That Apply" multiple="true">
          <md-option value="[[id]]" ng-repeat="(id, name) in taxonomies.subTermOptions[CONSTANTS.CODING_MARKING][CONSTANTS.CODING_MARKING_F1]" id="category_[[id]]">[[name]]</md-option>
        </md-select>
      </md-input-container>
      <md-input-container class="md-default-theme full-width-select">
        <md-select ng-model="product.taxonomyF2" placeholder="Select One" multiple="true">
          <md-option value="[[id]]" ng-repeat="(id, name) in taxonomies.subTermOptions[CONSTANTS.CODING_MARKING][CONSTANTS.CODING_MARKING_F2]" id="category_[[id]]">[[name]]</md-option>
        </md-select>
      </md-input-container>
    </div>

    <!-- Case erect/seal -->
    <div ng-if="product.taxonomy == CONSTANTS.CASE_ERECT_SEAL" layout="row">
      <md-input-container class="md-default-theme full-width-select">
        <md-select ng-model="product.taxonomyF1" placeholder="Select One" >
          <md-option value="[[id]]" ng-repeat="(id, name) in taxonomies.subTermOptions[CONSTANTS.CASE_ERECT_SEAL][CONSTANTS.CASE_ERECT_SEAL_F1]" id="category_[[id]]">[[name]]</md-option>
        </md-select>
      </md-input-container>
      <md-input-container class="md-default-theme full-width-select" ng-hide="product.isUsedInPrint">
        <md-select ng-model="product.taxonomyF2" placeholder="Select All That Apply" >
          <md-option value="[[id]]" ng-repeat="(id, name) in taxonomies.subTermOptions[CONSTANTS.CASE_ERECT_SEAL][CONSTANTS.CASE_ERECT_SEAL_F2]" id="category_[[id]]">[[name]]</md-option>
        </md-select>
      </md-input-container>
    </div>
```

If it is a multi-select I add multiple=true.

I want my single select to preselect even when my product.taxonomyF1 look like this:

```
taxonomyF1:{
  0: "19"
}
```

But it only works if it is like this:

```
taxonomyF1: 19
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my scenario I fixed it like this:

```
/**
 * Convert single select values from array to integer.
 *
 * @param product
 */
$scope.convertSingleSelects = function(p) {
  angular.forEach(p, function (object) {
    // If the taxonomy is one of these the taxonomyF1 field will be a single
    // select.
    var taxonomyForF1SingleSelects = [
      CONSTANTS.BAG_SEALING_CLOSING,
      CONSTANTS.CARTONING,
      CONSTANTS.CASE_ERECT_SEAL,
      CONSTANTS.CASE_TRAY_PACKING,
      CONSTANTS.CONTROLS_AND_MACHINE_COMPONENTS,
      CONSTANTS.CONVEYING_AND_ACCUMULATI0N,
      CONSTANTS.FILLING_CAPPING_DRY,
      CONSTANTS.FILLING_CAPPING_LIQUID_AND_VISCOUS,
      CONSTANTS.FORM_FILL_SEAL_HORIZONTAL,
      CONSTANTS.FORM_FILL_SEAL_VERTICAL,
      CONSTANTS.INSPECT_DETECT_CHECKWEIGH_VISION,
      CONSTANTS.LABELING,
      CONSTANTS.MULTIPACKING_SHRINK_BUNDLING,
      CONSTANTS.PALLETIZING_DEPALLETIZING,
      CONSTANTS.TAMPER_EVIDENCE_MACHINERY,
      CONSTANTS.ROBOTICS,
      CONSTANTS.WEIGHING_COMBINATION_SCALES
    ];

    // If the taxonomy is one of these the taxonomyF2 field will be a single
    // select.
    var taxonomyForF2SingleSelects = [
      CONSTANTS.CODING_MARKING,
      CONSTANTS.FILLING_CAPPING_LIQUID_AND_VISCOUS,
    ];

    // Setting the first value of the first index as the value.
    if (object.taxonomy != null || object.taxonomy != '') {
      if (taxonomyForF1SingleSelects.indexOf(object.taxonomy) != -1) {
        if (object.taxonomyF1[0] != undefined) {
          object.taxonomyF1 = object.taxonomyF1[0];
        }

        if (object.taxonomyF2[0] != undefined) {
          object.taxonomyF2 = object.taxonomyF2[0];
        }
      }
    }
  });
};
// Single selects are in an array so convert them to integers instead.
$scope.convertSingleSelects($scope.webProducts);
angular.forEach($scope.printProducts.taxonomies, function(object) {
  $scope.convertSingleSelects(object.products);
});
```